# Techniques to Avoid Problems with Django Migrations?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

I'm building an e-commerce website with Django 1.8 and PostgreSQL 9.4.  I'm interested in learning what techniques I can use when I change my database to avoid having problems with Django migrations, particularly in the event that I can't get migrations to run and I have to delete my migrations, rebuild my  database, and restore from backups.

In development, I've found that when I change my database schema and re-run migrations, they only run successfully about 50% of the time.  Clearly I'm doing some things wrong.  What's worse is that when migrations don't work, it's not always easy to understand exactly why they failed and how to modify my migration files so that they will run.  In those situations, I always have to delete the database and start over.  This is acceptable in development but it's not a good strategy when I go into production.

What are some "best practices" or "do's and don'ts" you follow when you modify your model classes/database schema so as to increase the probability that your Django migrations will run?  And are there any steps you take to ensure that you can restore your database in the event that your migrations won't run and you have to rebuild the database from scratch?  I should add that I'm a one-person startup so I don't have the conflict issues that a team working from the same code base would have.

Comment: You should post some of the example that what are the errors you get with migrations.

Comment: That's a good idea and I would but unfortunately I didn't record them before I rebuilt my database.

Comment: It's too broad like you can do fake migrate and you can edit the migration files by yourself to resolve errors. Then you can have nullable fields to avoid default value errors. Then another option would be to backup the dB then migrate then reload the dB. @William one more thought is that I don't agree with the answer below and I think it's a horrible idea

Comment: What's your current workflow?

Comment: I'm putting together a new workflow based on recent problems I've been having.  I'll share it with everyone in another day or so after I've received more feedback.

Answer (score 1):

These Techniques are what I'm using

1. Work locally in the same environment what I'm working in it on server. Same version of the Django and database server then push the migrations itself, don't ignore it, and migrate on the server using there migrations.
2. This one I used once that I migrate manually, I created the tables, indices, relations using sql commands manually and it worked properly too.

**I prefer the first one more**

Comment: First one will clutter your production server's migrations and dB states. Any way I don't understand the first one. How it will be different if you create one on server from your local migrations

Comment: When you use any VC like git, don't ignore your migration files, push it all and use them to migrate on the server too, as some developers ignore them and make migrations on the server again which is not efficient according to my perspective as it differs a lot and reduces the errors on migrations

Comment: Ok so if you create migrations from local and use them on server and second case you create the migration on server then wouldn't both be the same. Also this solution will be horrible if you have a team working on same project.

Comment: Yes I know because of conflicts and I handle it using some conventions to pull master before and resolving conflicts. I read a lot about migrations and the best techniques to avoid or reduce errors. I use my ways finally

Comment: Conflicts on VCS are other things my point is that other team members have to go through migrations conflicts because of one single shared migrations folder. Also second option that you mentioned is a really really really horrible idea. If you do that then you are just not using power or orm correctly

Comment: I tried it and worked properly and mention me if anyone suggest any good solution

Comment: Well anything can work but it is not a best practice anyway